# get button text using sender() always return error — 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

Using Qt Designer created a `Push Button`, then code:

```py
# import ...
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        qfile = QFile("test.ui")
        qfile.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        qfile.close()
        self.ui = QUiLoader().load(qfile)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        print(self.ui.sender().text())

app = QApplication([])
test = Test()
test.ui.show()
app.exec_()
```

When I clicked the button, getting error message:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

How can I get the button text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sender() method returns the object that emitted the signal if where it is invoked is a method that is called asynchronously, also only the sender() of the class to which the method belongs will be valid.

Considering the above, the Test class must be a QObject, and its sender() method must be invoked:

```py
import os

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtUiTools

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


class Test(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        filename = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIRECTORY, "test.ui")
        qfile = QtCore.QFile(filename)
        qfile.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)
        qfile.close()
        self.ui = QtUiTools.QUiLoader().load(qfile)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def buttonClicked(self):
        print(self.sender().text())


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    test = Test()
    test.ui.show()
    app.exec_()
```